# Как найти несколько последовательных значений в списке и получить их индексы?

Tags: python

К примеру у меня есть два списка:

```
list1 = ['Walking', '20', 'streets', 'uptown', 'or', 'downtown', 'in', 'Midtown', 'generally', 'covers', 'a', 'distance', 'of', 'approximately', 'one', 'mile', '.']

list2 = ['20','streets','uptown']
```

В `list1` содержится предложение, в `list2` несколько последовательно идущих частей предложения, индексы которых я хотел бы найти в `list1`. Как я могу это сделать?

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    if D[0] == L[i]:
        d,j = 1,1
        mas = []
        mas.append(True)
        ind = []
        ind.append(i)
        while d < len(D):
            if D[d] == L[i + j]:
                mas.append(True)
                ind.append(i+j)
                d += 1
                j += 1
            else:
                mas.append(False)
        if False not in mas:
            break
```

Написал такой код, как его можно улучшить?

Answer (score 1):

Искать в `list1` элемент `list2[0]`, как нашлось проверить следующие два. Если совпало - вывести индексы.